# Local Variable Reference Before Assignment

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.3

Ok so I'm making a program using Tkinter (3.3). The user submits a name, the name is then searched in the database `cards.cdb` which prints out it's information and then compares it to an online source `url`. It also displays the picture of the named thing using the function `picture`. So when the button is clicked it calls the `buttonclicked` function which then calls the two other functions.

```
from tkinter import *
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import Pydeck
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

root = Tk()
name=""
def buttonclicked():
    name()
    picture(text)

def name():
    all_lists=[] #all lists
    text = inputfield.get()
    Pydeck.loadDatabase('C://Users/Trevor/Desktop/Y-In Process/cards.cdb')
    cardName = Pydeck.getCardsFromName(text)
    if not cardName == "":
            c = Pydeck.Card(cardName)
    tex.insert(END, c.name)
    level="\nLevel %s" % c.level + " " + c.attribute + " " + c.typestring 
    tex.insert(END, level)
    atk="\nAtk: %s" % c.attack
    tex.insert(END, atk)
    defe="\nDef: %s" % c.defense
    tex.insert(END, defe)
    typestring='\n%s' %c.typestring
    desc='\n%s' %c.description
    seperator='\n--------------------\n'
    tex.insert(END, typestring)
    tex.insert(END, desc)
    tex.insert(END,seperator)
    #--
    url_name=c.name.replace(' ','_')
    url=('http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Tips:{}'.format(url_name))
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    content = soup.find('div',id='mw-content-text')
    links = content.findAll('a')
    link_lists = defaultdict(list)
    all_lists.append([link.get("title") for link in links])
    common_links = set(all_lists[0]).intersection(*all_lists[1:])
    omit_list=['None', 'Special Summon', 'Edit Searchable by section', 'Edit Special Summoned from the hand by section','Edit Special Summoned from the Deck by section','Edit Special Summoned from the Graveyard by section','Edit Easier Tribute Summons section','Edit Generic Tips section','Edit Traditional Format section']
    final=set(common_links)-set(omit_list)
    tex.insert(END,final)
    #--
    tex.see(END)             # Scroll if necessary


def picture(text):
    gifdir = "C:\\Users\\Trevor\\Desktop\\Y-In Process\\Pictures\\"
    Pydeck.loadDatabase('C://Users/Trevor/Desktop/Y-In Process/cards.cdb')
    cardName = Pydeck.getCardsFromName(text)
    if not cardName == "":
        c=Pydeck.Card(cardName)
    filename='{}.gif' .format(c.cardID)
    img = PhotoImage(file=gifdir+filename)
    can = Canvas(root)
    can.pack(fill=BOTH,side='left')
    can.config(width=img.width(), height=img.height())        
    can.create_image(2, 2, image=img, anchor=NW)

tex=Text(root)
tex.pack(side='right')
inputfield = Entry(root)
inputfield.pack(side='bottom')
but = Button(root,text="Enter Name", command = buttonclicked) #Calls name function
but.pack(side='bottom')
text = inputfield.get()


root.mainloop()
```

I'm getting the error

```
filename='{}.gif' .format(c.cardID)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment
```

I know that means `c` isn't being created but in the `picture` function I do define it however it doesn't recognize it.

Anybody have any suggestions cause I'm stumped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if not cardName == "":
    c=Pydeck.Card(cardName)
filename='{}.gif' .format(c.cardID)
```

And what happens if `cardName` *is* equal to "" ?

Since this is the only place `c` is initialized, if `cardName` is empty then you'll see this error.  You need to define what should happen is `cardName` is empty, and handle that condition accordingly.